# Is it possible to query the Visual Studio debugger and retrieve information about a variable similar to the Autos/Locals/Watch windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

The Visual Studio watch window is able to give a lot of information about a variable and its members. Is it at all possible to gain access to this information through an API exposed to C++?

Comment: I believe you'd have to read the PDB file, and memory.  This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2022

Comment: @ChrisMM I was afraid it may come to that :) thanks for the link!

Comment: @ChrisMM if you put that as an answer I'll checkmark it since this seems to be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not an easy way. Since you're using Visual Studio, you can use the generate program database (pdb) files. Microsoft does provide information on using the PDB files here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2022

From my (very limited) experience with PDB files, the PDBs must be on the same machine as the program is running on. Of course, you'll need to generate the symbol files (Debug Mode's default, or just enable the setting for other modes).